# Iterating through array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* make_array(int a, int b, int c) {
    int results[3] = { a, b, c };
    return &results[0];
}

int main() {
    int *results = make_array(5, 2, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "\narray member N:" << i << ": " << *results;
        results++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, `results` variable holds address of first member of array `[5, 2, 3]` (address of 5). When I do `results++` address should move 32 bits forward, so that `results` should be address of 2, but it logs following:

```
array member N:0: 5
array member N:1: 1434567088
array member N:2: 541456720
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're returning a temporary which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You want to return an array, so return something that represents an array without loss of information like pointers have. The prime choice would be `std::array<int, 3>`.

Comment: @101010 , chris,   I read original question and understood everything. Thank you ^_^